# Change style of fixed buttons when scrolling a page

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click any of the fixed buttons on the left pane (also fixed) the page scrolls to a certain section (each button corresponds to a section).

How can I achieve the reverse effect, like whenever I scroll to a section the corresponding button is highlighted?

Here is the code:

```css
.sidebar
{
 width:140px;
 height:100%;
 font-family:Rajdhani;
 background-image: url("./sidebar_background.jpg");
 color:white;
 float:left;
 position:fixed;
 display: block;
}
#about-content-container
{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 padding:1px;
 background-color:#FCB9B5;
}
#projects-content-container
{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 padding:1px;
 background-color:#B5EECB;
}
#contact-content-container
{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 padding:1px;
 background-color:#1F3541;
}
/*sidebar text on top left*/
.sidebar-section-title
{
 color:#A1DBF1;
 font-size:25px;
 left:25px;
 position:absolute;
 font-weight: bold;
}
/*-----------------------*/
/*sidebar 3 buttons container*/
.sidebar-navigation-buttons
{
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
 position:absolute;
 top:33.3%;
 left:10px;
 margin-left:12px;
 rotate:90deg;
}
/*-----------------------*/
/*sidebar generic button*/
.sidebar-section-button
{
 color:whitesmoke;
 background:none;
 border:none;
 font-family:Rajdhani;
 font-size:22.5px;
 width:100px;
 height:33px;
 margin-bottom:3px;
 display: inline-block;
 transition: 0.3s;
}
.sidebar-section-button:hover
{
 background-color: rgba(225, 239, 250, 0.6);
 color:white;
 font-weight: 200;
}
/*-----------------------*/
/*sidebar button corresponding to the section scrolled to*/
.sidebar-section-button-selected
{
 color:whitesmoke;
 background:none;
 border:1px solid transparent;
 font-family:Rajdhani;
 font-size:22.5px;
 width:100px;
 height:33px;
 margin-bottom:3px;
 display: inline-block;
 transition: 0.3s;
}
.sidebar-section-button-selected:hover
{
 border:1px solid rgba(225, 239, 250, 0.6);
 color:white;
 margin-bottom:2.5px;
}
```

```html
<aside class="sidebar"><p id="sidebar-navigation-title" class="sidebar-section-title">Welcome</p><br>
 <div id="sidebar-navigation-buttons" class="sidebar-navigation-buttons">
  <button id="sidebar-navigation-to-contact" class="sidebar-section-button" 
   onclick="ScrollToContact()">Contact</button>
  <button id="sidebar-navigation-to-projects" class="sidebar-section-button" 
   onclick="ScrollToProjects()">Projects</button>
  <button id="sidebar-navigation-to-top" style="font-weight:bolder;" 
   class="sidebar-section-button-selected" onclick="ScrollToTop()">About</button>
</div><br></aside>
<div id="about-content-container">
</div>
<div id="project-content-container">
</div>
<div id="contact-content-container">
</div>
```

I've tried with scrollTop and IntersectionObserver but nothing works.

From what I've tried it seems like window scroll event is not even happening.

Comment: try with intersectionobserver but with "sentinel". Between each section you put a div class="sentinel" (id=sentinel1, 2... or you check nth-child...). Now you observe all the classe sentinel. When one intersect, you check which one and you highligh your button

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getBoundingClientRect()` method and then calculate the distance from the top.

P.S: I added 2 second time out so you can see that the `.highlighted` is being added only when the link is on the screen

```js
const myAnchor = document.getElementById('myLink')

function isElementOutOfView(element) {
  const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
   return (
    rect.bottom < 0 || rect.top > window.innerHeight
  );
}

function handleScroll() {
   if (isElementOutOfView(myAnchor)) {
         myAnchor.classList.remove('highlighted');
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {
         myAnchor.classList.add('highlighted');
    },2000)

  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
```

```css
div{
  height:100vh;
  background:orange;
}

.highlighted {
  background-color: red;
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<a href="#section1" id="myLink">Scroll to Section 1</a>
<section id="section1">
  some text
  some text
  some text
  some text
  some text
</section>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written all the necessary codes for those functionalities with proper comments. If you want to change the style of the link on scroll just write it in the `active` class and it will be applied. Feel free to ask questions.

```js
// On scroll menu link activation
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollDistance = $(window).scrollTop();

    // Assign active class to links while scolling
    $('.page-section').each(function(i) {
        if (($(this).position().top - 10) <= scrollDistance) {
            $('#sidebar-navigation-buttons a.active').removeClass('active');
            $('#sidebar-navigation-buttons a').eq(i).addClass('active');
        }
    });
}).scroll();
```

```css
.sidebar
{
width:140px;
height:100%;
font-family:Rajdhani;
background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1400/1400?random=1");
color:white;
float:left;
position:fixed;
display: block;
}
#about-content-container
{
height:100%;
width:100%;
padding:1px;
background-color:#FCB9B5;
}
#projects-content-container
{
height:100%;
width:100%;
padding:1px;
background-color:#B5EECB;
}
#contact-content-container
{
height:100%;
width:100%;
padding:1px;
background-color:#1F3541;
}
/*sidebar text on top left*/
.sidebar-section-title
{
color:#A1DBF1;
font-size:25px;
left:25px;
position:absolute;
font-weight: bold;
}
/*-----------------------*/
/*sidebar 3 buttons container*/
.sidebar-navigation-buttons
{
height:100px;
width:100px;
position:absolute;
top:33.3%;
left:10px;
margin-left:12px;
rotate:90deg;
}
/*-----------------------*/
/*sidebar generic button*/
.sidebar-section-button
{
color:whitesmoke;
background:none;
border:none;
font-family:Rajdhani;
font-size:22.5px;
width:100px;
height:33px;
margin-bottom:3px;
display: inline-block;
transition: 0.3s;
}
.sidebar-section-button:hover
{
background-color: rgba(225, 239, 250, 0.6);
color:white;
font-weight: 200;
}
/*-----------------------*/
/*sidebar button corresponding to the section scrolled to*/
.sidebar-section-button-selected
{
color:whitesmoke;
background:none;
border:1px solid transparent;
font-family:Rajdhani;
font-size:22.5px;
width:100px;
height:33px;
margin-bottom:3px;
display: inline-block;
transition: 0.3s;
}
.sidebar-section-button-selected:hover
{
border:1px solid rgba(225, 239, 250, 0.6);
color:white;
margin-bottom:2.5px;
}

#about-content-container, #project-content-container, #contact-content-container{
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#about-content-container{
  background: rgb(187, 187, 187);
}

#project-content-container{
  background: rgb(172, 187, 253)
}

#contact-content-container{
  background: rgb(168, 253, 242)
}

/* put the style in the active class that you want to see in your links when scroll */
.active{
  border: 1px solid rgba(1, 255, 35, 0.61);
}
```

```html
<aside class="sidebar"><p id="sidebar-navigation-title" class="sidebar-section-title">Welcome</p><br>
    <div id="sidebar-navigation-buttons" class="sidebar-navigation-buttons">
      <!-- buttons are wrapped with anchor tags for onclick section scroll -->
     <a href="#contact-content-container"><button id="sidebar-navigation-to-contact" class="sidebar-section-button"
      onclick="ScrollToContact()">Contact</button></a>
     <a href="#project-content-container"><button id="sidebar-navigation-to-projects" class="sidebar-section-button" 
      onclick="ScrollToProjects()">Projects</button></a>
     <a href="#about-content-container"><button id="sidebar-navigation-to-top" style="font-weight:bolder;" 
      class="sidebar-section-button-selected" onclick="ScrollToTop()">About</button></a>
   </div><br></aside>

   <!-- assign "page-section" class to all the sections -->
   
   <div id="contact-content-container" class="page-section" style="text-align: center;">
    contact
   </div>
   <div id="project-content-container" class="page-section" style="text-align: center;">
    project
   </div>

   <div id="about-content-container" class="page-section" style="text-align: center;">
    about
   </div>   
   
   
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

OK, here I am putting all the codes together so that you can copy and use it easily.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .sidebar
    {
    width:140px;
    height:100%;
    font-family:Rajdhani;
    background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1400/1400?random=1");
    color:white;
    float:left;
    position:fixed;
    display: block;
    }
    #about-content-container
    {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:1px;
    background-color:#FCB9B5;
    }
    #projects-content-container
    {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:1px;
    background-color:#B5EECB;
    }
    #contact-content-container
    {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:1px;
    background-color:#1F3541;
    }
    /*sidebar text on top left*/
    .sidebar-section-title
    {
    color:#A1DBF1;
    font-size:25px;
    left:25px;
    position:absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
    /*-----------------------*/
    /*sidebar 3 buttons container*/
    .sidebar-navigation-buttons
    {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:33.3%;
    left:10px;
    margin-left:12px;
    rotate:90deg;
    }
    /*-----------------------*/
    /*sidebar generic button*/
    .sidebar-section-button
    {
    color:whitesmoke;
    background:none;
    border:none;
    font-family:Rajdhani;
    font-size:22.5px;
    width:100px;
    height:33px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    }
    .sidebar-section-button:hover
    {
    background-color: rgba(225, 239, 250, 0.6);
    color:white;
    font-weight: 200;
    }
    /*-----------------------*/
    /*sidebar button corresponding to the section scrolled to*/
    .sidebar-section-button-selected
    {
    color:whitesmoke;
    background:none;
    border:1px solid transparent;
    font-family:Rajdhani;
    font-size:22.5px;
    width:100px;
    height:33px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    }
    .sidebar-section-button-selected:hover
    {
    border:1px solid rgba(225, 239, 250, 0.6);
    color:white;
    margin-bottom:2.5px;
    }

    #about-content-container, #project-content-container, #contact-content-container{
      min-height: 100vh;
    }

    #about-content-container{
      background: rgb(187, 187, 187);
    }

    #project-content-container{
      background: rgb(172, 187, 253)
    }

    #contact-content-container{
      background: rgb(168, 253, 242)
    }

    /* put the style in the active class that you want to see in your links when scroll */
    .active{
      border: 1px solid rgba(1, 255, 35, 0.61);
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <aside class="sidebar"><p id="sidebar-navigation-title" class="sidebar-section-title">Welcome</p><br>
    <div id="sidebar-navigation-buttons" class="sidebar-navigation-buttons">
      <!-- buttons are wrapped with anchor tags for onclick section scroll -->
     <a href="#contact-content-container"><button id="sidebar-navigation-to-contact" class="sidebar-section-button"
      onclick="ScrollToContact()">Contact</button></a>
     <a href="#project-content-container"><button id="sidebar-navigation-to-projects" class="sidebar-section-button" 
      onclick="ScrollToProjects()">Projects</button></a>
     <a href="#about-content-container"><button id="sidebar-navigation-to-top" style="font-weight:bolder;" 
      class="sidebar-section-button-selected" onclick="ScrollToTop()">About</button></a>
   </div><br></aside>

   <!-- assign "page-section" class to all the sections -->
   
   <div id="contact-content-container" class="page-section" style="text-align: center;">
    contact
   </div>
   <div id="project-content-container" class="page-section" style="text-align: center;">
    project
   </div>

   <div id="about-content-container" class="page-section" style="text-align: center;">
    about
   </div>   
   
   
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <script>
    // On scroll menu link activation
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollDistance = $(window).scrollTop();

        // Assign active class to links while scolling
        $('.page-section').each(function(i) {
            if (($(this).position().top - 10) <= scrollDistance) {
                $('#sidebar-navigation-buttons a.active').removeClass('active');
                $('#sidebar-navigation-buttons a').eq(i).addClass('active');
            }
        });
    }).scroll();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I click 'Run code snippet' it works as expected but in the browser it doesn't work.

Comment: OK, I have put all the codes together (in another version). Just copy-paste all the codes from here to put into a new file and save it and then try. It must work.